# A question about a proof concerning sigma algebras of open sets and rectangles.

Tags: measure-theory

While proving $\sigma(\mathcal J_\mathrm{rat}^{n,o})=\sigma(\mathcal O^n)$ in the book "Measures, Integrals, and Martingales" the author does the following:

If $U \in \mathcal O^n$ we have $$U= \bigcup_{I\in \mathcal J_\mathrm{rat}^{o,n}, I\subset U} I \tag {3.2}$$
 In proving that $U$ is a subset of the union he takes $x\in U$ and since $U$ is open there exists $\varepsilon $ such that $B(x,\varepsilon ) \subset U$. He then says we can inscribe a square in the ball which we can shrink to a rectangle $I=I(x)\in \mathcal J _\mathrm{rat}^{n,o}$ containing $x$. (Why doesn't this prove that $U \subset \bigcup_{I\in \mathcal J_\mathrm{rat}^{o,n}, I\subset U} I$?)

The next part made no sense to me:

Since every rectangle $I$ is uniquely determined by its main diagonal (Why?) there are at most $\# (\Bbb{Q}^n \times \Bbb{Q}^n)\text{ (why?)}=\#\Bbb{N}$ many $I$ in the union $3.2$ thus $U\in \mathcal O^n \subset \sigma (\mathcal J_\mathrm{rat}^{o,n})$ (Again why?)

I'm using the same notation as [here](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Characterization_of_Euclidean_Borel_Sigma-Algebra#Theorem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $x\in U$, $I(x)$ is contained in $U$ and belongs to $\mathcal I_{\operatorname{rat}}^{o,n}$. Since $U=\bigcup_{x\in U}I(x)$, we have the wanted inclusion.

In the last part, the author means that the union of the RHS in (3.2) can be rewritten as a countable union, in order to make appear $U$ as a countable union of rectangle with rational endpoints. One can check that two rectangles $\prod_{j=1}^n[a_i,b_i]$ and $\prod_{j=1}^n[a'_i,b'_i]$ are equal if and only if $a_i=a'_i$ and $b_i=b'_i$.